# Groovy regex/pattern matching

Tags: regex, groovy

How do we do regex matching in groovy, what will be the regex in groovy for below example?

```
Example : f2376 Regex: (anyLetter)(followed by 4 digits)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pretty simple with groovy

`"f1234" ==~ /[a-z]\d{4}/`

Note that the regex `[a-z]\d{4}` means any of the characters a-z once, followed by exactly 4 digits, and can be probably be used with any language that handles regex, not just groovy.

In my console I tested for just lower case letters, but to handle upper case too just do

`"f1234" ==~ /[a-zA-Z]\d{4}/`

[image]

Comment: \w will match not only letters!