# Problem with groovy and regex matching groups

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm getting here after reading some other questions and examples like:

[Groovy syntax for regular expression matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764387/groovy-syntax-for-regular-expression-matching)

[Groovy regex/pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772497/groovy-regex-pattern-matching)

Also this documentation I found online:
https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/

I was playing with it and I have what I think is a very basic regex but by some reason I always get no match.

So imagining I have a git url something like this:
"ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/project/repo.git"

I want to extract in my groovy pipeline the project and repo itself:
"ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/([a-zA-Z-*]*)/([a-zA-Z-*]*).git" (maybe there are smarter ways of doing this match but still should work)

Anyway the problem is that I'm testing this and at the moment I can't even make the simple ssh match, last alone my groups.
It works fine in an online regex tester
[image]

But it does not work in the groovy playground online.

This is the example (I'm testing it here https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/):

This input:

```
GIT_URL='ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/project/repo.git'

def match = GIT_URL =~ /ssh:\/\/git@bitbucket\.sits\.net\/([a-zA-Z-_]*)\/([a-zA-Z-_]*)\.git/

println match
```

Outputs no match:

```
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=ssh://git@bitbucket\.sits\.net/([a-zA-Z-_]*)/([a-zA-Z-_]*)\.git region=0,45 lastmatch=]
```

I've tried a few things but not even ssh match works

```
GIT_URL='ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/project/repo.git'

def match = GIT_URL =~ /ssh/

println match 
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=ssh region=0,45 lastmatch=]
```

I thought it could be a problem in the tool but in my Jenkins pipeline it also does not work.

Also the example from the other question:

```
def match2 = "f1234" =~ /[a-z]\d{4}/
println match2
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=[a-z]\d{4} region=0,5 lastmatch=]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave Groovy execute the right matcher method itself, just use

```java
String GIT_URL='ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/project/repo.git'
def match = GIT_URL =~ /ssh:\/\/git@bitbucket\.sits\.net\/([a-zA-Z_-]*)\/([a-zA-Z_-]*)\.git/
if (match) { 
    println match[0][1]
    println match[0][2]
} else {
    println 'No match' 
}
```

See the Groovy demo.

With `=~` operator, you actually tell Groovy to find partial matches inside longer strings, with `==~`, you require full string match. All you need is `if (match)` to trigger matching. The `match` will contain all matches, so you get the first one via the zeroth index, and then you have an access to Group 1 via `[1]` and to Group 2 using `[2]`.

Regex tip: always put `-` at the end of the character class if you mean to match a literal `-` char.

Answer (score 0):

this was actually a bit not what I was expecting but I forgot to call the method matches()

```
GIT_URL='ssh://git@bitbucket.sits.net/project/repo.git'

def match = GIT_URL =~ /ssh:\/\/git@bitbucket\.sits\.net\/([a-zA-Z-_]*)\/([a-zA-Z-_]*)\.git/
match.matches()
println match.group(1)
println match.group(2)
project
repo
```